How Does Apple Verify the Consistency Between Activation Lock Codes and Hashes?
I am currently developing an Apple MDM service and encountered some confusion while reviewing Apple's Activation Lock documentation. Activation Lock involves two steps:
Locking the device:
I generated the code and hash using the example provided in Apple's official documentation: Activation Lock a Device. Using Apple's API at https://mdmenrollment.apple.com/device/activationlock, I lock the device by passing the hash as the escrow_key.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

#define MCBYPASS_CODE_LENGTH 31 // Excluding terminating null.
#define MCBYPASS_CODE_BUFFER_LENGTH 32 // Including terminating null.
#define MCBYPASS_RAW_BYTES_LENGTH 16
#define MCBYPASS_HASH_LENGTH CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
#define RANDOM_BYTES_LENGTH 16
#define SALT_LENGTH 4
#define INPUT_BITS 128
#define BITS_PER_BYTE 8
#define BITS_PER_SYMBOL 5

NSString* createNewActivationLockBypassCodeOutHash(NSString** outHash);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* outHash = nil;
        NSString* code = createNewActivationLockBypassCodeOutHash(&outHash);
        NSLog(@"Generated Code: %@", code);
        NSLog(@"Generated Hash: %@", outHash);
    }
    return 0;
}

NSString* createNewActivationLockBypassCodeOutHash(NSString** outHash) {
    static const char kSymbols[] = "0123456789ACDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXYZ";
    static const int kDashPositions[] = { 5, 10, 14, 18, 22 };
    char rawBytes[MCBYPASS_RAW_BYTES_LENGTH];
    char code[MCBYPASS_CODE_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    uint8_t hash[MCBYPASS_HASH_LENGTH];
    uint8_t salt[SALT_LENGTH] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    arc4random_buf(rawBytes, RANDOM_BYTES_LENGTH);
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, rawBytes, RANDOM_BYTES_LENGTH, salt, SALT_LENGTH,
                         kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, 50000, hash, CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    if (outHash) {
        NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:MCBYPASS_HASH_LENGTH * 2 + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < MCBYPASS_HASH_LENGTH; i++) {
            [str appendFormat:@"%02X", hash[i]];
        }
        *outHash = [NSString stringWithString:str];
    }

    int outputCharacterCount = 0;
    const int* nextDashPosition = kDashPositions;
    char* outputCursor = code;
    uint8_t* inputCursor = (uint8_t*)rawBytes;
    int bitsProcessed = 0;
    int bitOffsetIntoByte = 0;

    while (bitsProcessed <= (INPUT_BITS - BITS_PER_SYMBOL)) {
        int bitsThisByte = (bitOffsetIntoByte < BITS_PER_BYTE - BITS_PER_SYMBOL ?
                            BITS_PER_SYMBOL : BITS_PER_BYTE - bitOffsetIntoByte);
        int bitsNextByte = (bitsThisByte < BITS_PER_SYMBOL ? BITS_PER_SYMBOL - bitsThisByte : 0);

        uint8_t value = (((*inputCursor << bitOffsetIntoByte) & 0xff) >> (BITS_PER_BYTE - bitsThisByte));
        bitOffsetIntoByte += BITS_PER_SYMBOL;
        if (bitOffsetIntoByte >= BITS_PER_BYTE) {
            bitOffsetIntoByte -= BITS_PER_BYTE;
            inputCursor++;
        }

        if (bitsNextByte) {
            value <<= bitsNextByte;
            value |= (*inputCursor >> (BITS_PER_BYTE - bitsNextByte));
        }

        *outputCursor++ = kSymbols[value];
        if (++outputCharacterCount == *nextDashPosition) {
            ++nextDashPosition;
            *outputCursor++ = '-';
        }

        bitsProcessed += BITS_PER_SYMBOL;
    }

    int bitsRemaining = INPUT_BITS - bitsProcessed;
    if (bitsRemaining) {
        uint8_t value = (((*inputCursor << bitOffsetIntoByte) & 0xff) >> (BITS_PER_BYTE - bitsRemaining));
        *outputCursor++ = kSymbols[value];
    }
    *outputCursor = '\0';
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:code];
}


Unlocking the device:
According to Apple's documentation: Creating and Using Bypass Codes, the device is unlocked by submitting the code via the API at https://deviceservices-external.apple.com/deviceservicesworkers/escrowKeyUnlock.
Both locking and unlocking the device work properly. However, I have a question: since the code is generated from random rawBytes, and I only submit the hash (not the rawBytes) when locking the device, how does the Apple server verify that the hash and code are consistent when unlocking the device?

Apple's server can generate the hash from the code that you submit and verify that the hashes match

@Paulw11 When enabling the activation lock, the provided input is the hash, while disabling the activation lock requires the code. The hash is calculated from the rawBytes, so without the rawBytes, it is impossible to determine if a certain hash corresponds to a specific code.

The rawbytes are the code. The code you send to apple is just the rawbytes converted to hexadecimal digits interpolated at specific positions with "-". It is trivial for Apple to reverse this process to obtain the rawbytes and then generate the hash.

@Paulw11 I am not familiar with Objective-C code, and I have also consulted a friend who uses Objective-C. He said that it's not possible to calculate a hash value from code without rawBytes. Could you provide a piece of Objective-C code that verifies whether a specified hash corresponds to a certain code? Thank you very much!

The code is the rawbytes, they are just converted from 16 bytes to 32 hex characters. If the first raw byte is 0x45 and I send the string "45" it is simple enough to convert those two characters back to the single byte 0x45. Do that for all 32 hex characters and you have the original 16 raw bytes. Apple can then calculate the hash and then compare that with the hash that was sent previously.
